# Derivative of $f(x)=\int_{x}^{\sqrt {x^2+1}} \sin (t^2) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives

> Derivative of $f(x)=\int_{x}^{\sqrt {x^2+1}} \sin (t^2) dt$

Firstly I wanted to calculate $\int \sin (t^2) dt$ and then use $x$ and $\sqrt {x^2+1}$. But this antiderivative not exist so how can I do this? Is this function at all possible to count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(t)=\sin(t^2)$.

$f$ is continuous at $\Bbb R$, thus

$\displaystyle{F: x\mapsto \int_0^xf(t)dt}$ is differentiable at $\Bbb R$ and for all $x\in \Bbb R$,

$$F'(x)=f(x)=\sin(x^2)$$

but

$$G(x)=\int_x^{\sqrt{x^2+1}}f(t)dt=$$
$$F(\sqrt{x^2+1})-F(x)$$

with $x\mapsto \sqrt{x^2+1}$ differentiable at $\Bbb R$.
thus by chain rule, $G$ is differentiable at $\Bbb R$ and

$$G'(x)=\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}F'(\sqrt{x^2+1})-F'(x)$$

$$=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}\sin(x^2+1)-\sin(x^2).$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which says that if $$I(x) = \int_0^x \sin(t^2)\,{\rm d}t,$$then $I'(x) = \sin(x^2)$. Now observe that $f(x) = I(\sqrt{x^2+1}) - I(x)$ and use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Lebinitz rule.

$$f'(x) = \sin(x^2+1) \times \frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}} - \sin(x^2)$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $g(x)=\int_0^{x} \sin (t^{2})dt$. Then $f(x)=g(\sqrt {1+x^{2}}) -g(x)$. ALso $g'(x)=\sin (x^{2})$. Can you now compute $g'$ using Chain rule?